# TableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: Not getting called with UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using a UITableView which displaying a list of user. I have implemented the delegate method:

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to delete a user record by swiping left on the cell, It was working fine, But now i add UIPanGestureRecognizer to the controller to go back by right swiping in the view. Now here the problem is the tableView delegate method not getting called properly. So any help/suggestion would be appreciated how to handle the case. Thanks

here is my UIPanGestureRecognizer Action:

```
-(void)performAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){

    velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Velocity X: %f Y: %f",velocity.x,velocity.y);
}

else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){


    BOOL isHorizentalMotion = fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y);
    BOOL isHorizentallyLeft = velocity.x < 0 ? YES : NO;
    BOOL isHorizentallyRight = velocity.x > 0 ? YES : NO;

    if (isHorizentalMotion && isHorizentallyRight) {

        NSLog(@"RIGHT GESTURE");

        [self menuClicked:nil];
    }

}
```

}

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard:)];
 tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method

just implement in your .m file no need to call

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer velocityInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
    return fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y);
}
```